# Converting spatial objects to lists

Tags: r, sp

I have a SpatialLinesData frame with 1657 different routes.  Each route is of a different length and has a differing number of nodes or waypoints (lat, lon).

For example, `routes@line[[87]]` is made up of 7 waypoints.  I am wondering if there is a simple method to extract the lat, lon coordinates, or [,1] and[,2] of every route and convert them into a list of 1657.

When I try this with one `routes@line[[87]]`, for example, I get an error:

```
    > as.list(routes@lines[[87]])
    Error in as.list.default(routes@lines[[87]]) : 
      no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Does a method exist for converting line objects to lists?

```
    > str(routes)
    Formal class 'SpatialLinesDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 4 slots
      ..@ data       :'data.frame': 1657 obs. of  3 variables:
      .. ..$ start_time: Factor w/ 1631 levels "2016/09/09 00:00:02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
      .. ..$ duration  : int [1:1657] 786 1248 738 786 651 660 616 889 408 475 ...
      .. ..$ difftime  :Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:1657] 2 4 19 67 92 119 170 202 206 213 ...
      .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
      ..@ lines      :List of 1657

    > routes@lines[[87]]
    An object of class "Lines"
    Slot "Lines":
    [[1]]
    An object of class "Line"
    Slot "coords":
              [,1]     [,2]
    [1,] -79.92976 43.25867
    [2,] -79.92984 43.25865
    [3,] -79.92986 43.25868
    [4,] -79.92989 43.25870
    [5,] -79.92983 43.25871
    [6,] -79.92983 43.25871
    [7,] -79.92983 43.25871



    Slot "ID":
    [1] "87"
```

Comment: Use ggplot2:: fortify or spbabel::sptable for a straight forward dataframe of coordinates with the grouping attributes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312908/converting-spatial-slots-to-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pipe the data into an empty list using a double bracket index.

```
routes.list <- list()
for(i in 1:nrows(routes)) { routes.list[[i]] <- routes@lines[[i]] }
```

If you only want the coordinates and not the spatial object, just wrap each line in a call to coordinates such; `coordinates(routes[i,])`